# What is analogue of lua `local variable = var1 or var2` in C#?

Tags: c#, coronasdk

Im quite familiar with lua and I want to perform w simple variable set value.

In lua:

```
local variable = var1 or var 2
```

Which means if `var1` exists, set `variable`'s  value to `var1`, otherwise set it to `var2`.
How to perform such equation in C#? I just learn Unity 3D an wonder how to perform such thing.

Edit

So in my particular case:

```
public GameObject to (GameObject localTarget, string[][] transitionParams)
{
    int delay = transitionParams.delay;
    int timer = transitionParams.timer;

    int x = transitionParams.x;
    int y = transitionParams.y;
}
```

How to check if those params are set? Each one of `transitionParams` may be `nil`. They are all optiona.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense in C# in which local variables are defined at compile time. If a variable doesn't 'exist', code won't compile.

Comment: C# doesn't allow slicing a single field from an entire array the way you show, otherwise it's a matter of checking for `null` just as dasblinkenlight says in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Lua, C# does not let you reference variables that do not exist. It does, however, let you reference variables that are set to `null`, and skip `null` values, like this:

```
var variable = var1 ?? var2;
```

This would set `variable` to `var1`'s value if it is not `null`; otherwise, it would set it to `var2`'s value.

In order for this to work `var1` must be *nullable*, i.e. it should be a variable of type `class`, or a variable of `struct` type `System.Nullable<T>`.

> I simply would like to pass `x`, `y`, `name`, `delay` and `timer` values in a single array. `name` would be a `string`, rest of them `int`. `name` is the only value that is required.

C# offers a mechanism for passing named parameters. If you combine that with the ability to set default values, you can build an API that looks like this:

```
public GameObject(
    string name
,   int? x = null
,   int? y = null
,   int? delay = null
,   int? timer = null
);
```

You can call it using any of 16 possible combinations of optional items by providing parameter names:

```
var unicorn = new GameObject("unicorn", x:12, delay:24);
var bunny = new GameObject("bunny", x:40, y:30, timer:0);
```

Comment: Ok, so if my function may receive 4 variables, may 3 of them be optional? so I may pass them or not? And how to assign them to local variables in function?

Comment: @Lukis You can make a variable optional by supplying a default value for it, e.g. `void foo(int a, int? b = null, int? c = null, int? d = null)` takes at least one and at most four arguments. If the caller does not supply an argument, your method sees its value as `null`. Once a parameter is passed into your function, it behaves like a local variable, i.e. changes to it are not visible to the caller. The only exceptions are `ref` and `out` parameters.

Comment: Sounds good. But how to pass array with optional values? I recently added my sample code to a question

Comment: @Lukis The code that you have added does not make much sense, because you are passing an array of arrays of strings, and then try accessing `delay`, `timer`, `x`, and `y` attributes on it. An array of arrays of strings does not have such attributes. Instead of guessing the signature of the method, could you show how you want your method to be called, with all possible combinations of parameters that you want it to receive?

Comment: I simply would like to pass `x`, `y`, `name`, `delay` and `timer` values in a single array. Name would be a `string`, rest of them `int`. Name is the only value that is required.